# Authentication Failed when Lumen is connected to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, lumen, mongodb-atlas

I am new to MongoDB Atlas and am having trouble connecting Lumen with the mongoDB atlas cluster. the error message I received was Authentication failed.

[image]

the code I use to connect is as follows:

```
'mongodb_atlas' => [
      'driver'   => 'mongodb',
      'dsn'      => 'mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@mycluster.99xxx.mongodb.net/mydbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
      'database' => 'mydbname',
    ]
```

even though the username and password that I entered in dsn match those in MongoDB Atlas. is there something wrong with my code? how is the solution? I am very grateful if anyone can help.

note:

> Lumen that I use version 8.x, and PHP version 8.x

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [`jenssegers/laravel-mongodb`](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) package to connect to MongoDB.

You can check the structure for MongoDB DSN for **standalone**, **shared cluster** and **replica set** in the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format).

To connect to MongoDB Atlas the `dsn` is constructed as follows

```php
'mongodb_conn' => [
  'driver' => 'mongodb',
  'dsn'=>'mongodb://username:password@host1,host2/defaultauthdb?ssl=true&replicaSet=replicaSet&authSource=admin',
  'database' => 'my_data',
]
```

You're missing the `ssl=true` param, but that needs to be supported by your server. So have an eye on that.

I know that you're using `+srv` to use TLS/SSL connection but maybe the other format from above works better.